# Stop animating submenu on multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a sub menu that slides from left off screen (left: -662px) to left: 342px. This is triggered on clicking a primary menu item.

The submenu retreats back to -662px if the primary menu is clicked again. My issue is if the primary menu item is click in rapid succession the submenu element proceeds to move across the page 342px at a time. It doesnt move back and forth as expected.

This only happens during the elements animations - it the primary menu item is clicked after the submenu has finised animating it moves back to -662px as it should.

I have tried adding .stop() to no affect. Does anyone know how to fix this up?

```
//IF IS SHOWN, HIDE
$("#menu ul li").click(function() {
  $("#menu ul li ul").each(function() {
   //GET SUBMENUS CURRENT POSITION  
    var sub2pos = $(this).css('left');
       //IF MARGIN IS GREATER THE 340PX HIDE THE MENU
        sub2pos = parseInt(sub2pos);
        if(sub2pos > 340){
         $(this).stop().animate({ left: '-=662px' }, 400 );
      }
  });//END EACHFUNCTION
});//END 1st CLICK FUNCTION

//IF IS HIDDEN, SHOW
$("#menu ul li").click(function() {
      //GET SUBMENUS CURRENT POSITION
      var sub2pos = $(this).children('ul').css('left');
      //IF MARGIN IS LESS THEN 342PX SHOW THE MENU
       sub2pos = parseInt(sub2pos);
      if(sub2pos < 342){
           $(this).children('ul').delay(500).stop().animate({ left: '+=662px' }, 400 );
      }
});//END 2nd CLICK FUNCTION
```

EDIT: I created a fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/q5Htx/19/ Note what happens if you click the menu item rapidly

Comment: Note that sub2pos < "342px" is string comparison, it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @Bemmu you are right and I have fixed it, but my original problem still prevails

Comment: you need to log your sub2pos *console.log(sub2pos)* and see what is happening in quick succession of clicks on parent :).

Comment: @TonyShih yes it registers different values on each click, depending on the sub menus position. Hmm I need a way to have the click only become availble again after the animation is compelte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the issue:

I should have been more specific on the 2nd if statement where the submenu slide out. Instead of `<342` I should have specified the negative position of the element: `<= -662`. That way the animation would not be triggered if the div was at, say, `left 150px` or anywhere else in between +342 and -662.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a few things:

Move the showing and hiding logic to a function with if-elseif blocks to decide which one to execute.

```
function menuClickHandler(menu){//logic goes here}
```

Then bind the .click event only once and call that function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#menu ul li").on('click', function(e) { 
        menuClickHandler($(this)); 
    });
});
```

Then orchestrate unbind/bind of click event in your function before and after animating the menu.

More code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q5Htx/28/) in an update to your fiddle

-notice that I'm using on/off in the code. Used bind/unbind to explain because they sound grammatically correct.